# Plot a frequency table in R

Tags: r, graph

I have a table with the results of a survey. I mean, I don't have the full survey data, only the frequency tables, Likert scale counts. Is it possible to graph this table in R?

The table looks like this:
Question 1: (`response` is a factor)

```
response count
1        5
2        6
3        2
4        2
5        1
```

It's very easy to do it in Excel, but i can't in R. The only thing I could think of was to repeat the table values ​​based on the count, but there must be a simpler way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `ggplot2` approach. You can set your `response` as x variable and `count` as y variable and use `geom_col()` in order to display bars. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(response),y=count))+
  geom_col(color='black',fill='cyan3')+
  xlab('Response')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(response = 1:5, count = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A histogram-like chart from `plot`

```
plot(df,type = "h")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If we wanted to do this without having to install any package, use the `base R` methods with either a named vector in a single-line

```
barplot(setNames(df$count, df$response))
```

Or with the formula method for data.frame

```
barplot(count ~ response, df)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(response = 1:5, count = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```